# Pandas: extract columns from multiple dataframes to a new dataframe based on common column name

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 datasets imported from Excel containing total_budget for schools for 2013, 2014, 2015 and 2016. All dataset have a common column with the ID code for each school (Column LAESTAB).

I want a new dataset with the common column LAESTAB (same values across the 4 datasets) on the left and the columns total2013, total2014, total2015 and total2016 (from different datasets) next.

I also want to get rid of the rest of the data, including those school IDs that are not present in all datasets.

I'll try to further elaborate it in an example:

Here's an example of one of the Excel datasets:

```
>>> print cuts2016.head()

    LA_codelocal_authority_name    UPIN  URN  LAESTAB  \
0      201       City of London  500000  0.0  2013614   
1      202               Camden  500005  0.0  2022095   
2      202               Camden  500007  0.0  2022219   
3      202               Camden  500012  0.0  2022502   
4      202               Camden  500014  0.0  2022603   

       School Name Academy?    Phase Provider Type  \
0  Sir John Cass's Foundation Primary School       No  Primary        School   
1                     Carlton Primary School       No  Primary        School   
2                       Fleet Primary School       No  Primary        School   
3                        Rhyl Primary School       No  Primary        School   
4                    Torriano Primary School       No  Primary        School   


   MFG protection (+ve) or capping/scaling (-ve)  total2016  \
0                                          35000    1659000   
1                                          68000    1956000   
2                                         -10000    1059000   
3                                          97000    2234000   
4                                              0    2284000
```

Another Excel dataset for 2005:

```
print cuts2015.head()
   LA_code local_authority_name  UPIN     URN  LAESTAB  \
0      201       City of London   NaN  100000  2013614   
1      202               Camden   NaN  100008  2022019   
2      202               Camden   NaN  100009  2022036   
3      202               Camden   NaN  100010  2022065   
4      202               Camden   NaN  100011  2022078   

                                 school_name    Phase Provider Type  \
0  Sir John Cass's Foundation Primary School  Primary        School   
1                      Argyle Primary School  Primary        School   
2                    Beckford Primary School  Primary        School   
3                   Brecknock Primary School  Primary        School   
4                  Brookfield Primary School  Primary        School   

  Basic Entitlement Total Funding Deprivation Total Funding total_pre_MFG  \
0                       1,206,000                   215,000     1,644,000   
1                       1,333,000                   367,000     2,068,000   
2                       1,482,000                   359,000     2,221,000   
3                       1,234,000                   348,000     1,974,000   
4                       1,436,000                   256,000     2,028,000   

  MFG protection (+ve) or capping/scaling (-ve) total2015  \
0                                             0   1644000   
1                                        25,000   2093000   
2                                             0   2221000   
3                                        72,000   2046000   
4                                       -58,000   1970000
```

The final result I would need is as follows (should show total2014 and total2013):

```
LAESTAB  total2016    total2015   etc...\
2013614  1956000      1644000      
2022019  1059000      2093000 
2022036  2234000      2221000 
2022065  2284000      1970000 
...
```

I have tried 'reduce' as in below but it returns 0 rows × 66 columns.

```
dataframe_list = [cuts2013, cuts2014, cuts2015, cuts2016]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='LAESTAB'), dataframe_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is using merge as Mainul Islam pointed out. Here you have to do 3 merge operations to merge 4 dataframes. Otherwise, you can concatenate all the 4 dataframes and do a groupby operation.

```
dataframe_list = [cuts2013, cuts2014, cuts2015, cuts2016]
total = pd.concat(dataframe_list)
total = total.groupby('LAESTAB')['total2013', 'total2014', 'total2015','total2016'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge the dataframes SQL style using the LAESTAB column and then delete columns from `data_merged` as necessary.

```
import pandas as pd
data_merged = pd.merge(cuts2016,cuts2015,on = "LAESTAB")
```

For more on merging you can check the following links:

http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_join_merge_dataframe.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: It only works with 2 datasets. What can I do for merging 4 datasets? `Error 
TypeError: Could not compare ['left'] with block values`

Comment: let us say you have datasets named `dataset_1, dataset_2,dataset_3, and  dataset_4`.

Once you have merged `dataset_1` and `dataset_2`, let us say you get a dataframe named `merged_dataframe`. 

Now merge `dataset_3` with `merged_dataframe` and repeat the process with `dataset_4`. Not the best of ideas, but it should do the job.

Comment: tried that @mainul-islam but returns 0 rows `data_merged2 = pd.merge(data_merged,cuts2014,on = "LAESTAB")`